# cv2.resize() unable to use with (y, x) matrix

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I'm trying to calibrate HD Camera, resolution 1280x720.

I need it to be resized after applying undistort function to size 640x480.
So it's changing aspect ratio from 16:9 to 4:3.

In my opencv application anything works flawless besides saving (y, x) positions of calibrated camera. I need it because, binary output file is working with flashplayer application that reads this changed camera (y, x) positions and applyies it to original camera view that is being grabbed by flashplayer.

Binary file with cv2.resize():

```
def generate_grid(rows, cols):
    """Generate grid filed with y,x values at desired size"""
    cc, rr = np.meshgrid(np.arange(cols, dtype=np.uint16), np.arange(rows, dtype=np.uint16))
    return np.dstack([rr, cc])


camera_size = (1280, 720)
binary_size = (320, 240)
raw_grid = generate_grid(camera_size[1], camera_size[0])
undist_grid = cv2.undistort(raw_grid, camera_matrix, dist_coeffs)
resized_grid = cv2.resize(undist_grid, (320, 240))
transformed_grid = cv2.warpPerspective(resized_grid, transformed_matrix, binary_size)

with open(path_to_binary_file, "wb") as binary_file:
    num_bytes_written = binary_file.write(transformed_grid)
    print(transformed_grid.shape)
    print("Wrote %d bytes." % num_bytes_written)
```

Output image read by flashplayer apllication:

[image]

Binary file with naive algorithm:

```
def generate_grid(rows, cols):
    """Generate grid filed with y,x values at desired size"""
    cc, rr = np.meshgrid(np.arange(cols, dtype=np.uint16), np.arange(rows, dtype=np.uint16))
    return np.dstack([rr, cc])


camera_size = (1280, 720)
binary_size = (320, 240)
raw_grid = generate_grid(camera_size[1], camera_size[0])
undist_grid = cv2.undistort(raw_grid, camera_matrix, dist_coeffs)
resized_grid = generate_grid(480, 640)
_resized_grid = generate_grid(binary_size[1], binary_size[0])

for y in range(undist_grid.shape[0]):
    for x in range(undist_grid.shape[1]):
        if y % 2 != 0 and x % 2 != 0:
            yy = int(y / 2)
            xx = int(x / 2)
            resized_grid[yy, xx, :] = undist_grid[y, x] / 2

        
for y in range(resized_grid.shape[0]):
    for x in range(resized_grid.shape[1]):
        if y % 2 != 0 and x % 2 != 0:
            yy = int(y / 2)
            xx = int(x / 2)
            _resized_grid[yy, xx, :] = resized_grid[y, x] / 2

transformed_grid = cv2.warpPerspective(_resized_grid, transformed_matrix, binary_size)

with open(path_to_binary_file, "wb") as binary_file:
    num_bytes_written = binary_file.write(transformed_grid)
    print(transformed_grid.shape)
    print("Wrote %d bytes." % num_bytes_written)
```

Output image read by flashplayer application:

[image]

So in the naive case, I can see that this transformation from 1280x720 to 640x480 is wrong because normally it would be 640x360.

My questions are:

1. Am I using the cv2.resize() function in the wrong way?
2. Is there a better way to generate (y, x) points from undistorted camera view?
3. How can I implement resize 1280x720 to 640x480 in naive algorithm?

@Edit

My application is working okay.

I'm stuck on transferring, changed camera data to binary file.

Comment: take a few steps back. put all that code aside (and never look at it again). explain where you are, where you want to go, and why.

Comment: resizing while changing the aspect ratio... three options: stretch, pad/letterboxing, or cropping. which would you like?

Comment: you might wanna know of `initUndistortRectifyMap` which can take identity matrices for the things you don't care about (rotation, translation)

Comment: I would prefer stretching

Comment: then that's simply `cv.resize`

Comment: Okay, so can I use it to resize (720, 1280) array or (y, x) values? Or am I missing something?

Comment: your index array... hm yes, that should also work. however, the indices themselves will still have the same range, so when you use that index array for lookup, the source image would have to be the same size. the output would be the same size as the index array (that you resized).

Comment: So ```resized_grid = cv2.resize(undist_grid, (320, 240))``` is not correct? undist_grid size is 720x1280

Comment: opencv takes (width,height) tuples for sizes, numpy shapes are (height,width) or (height,width,channels)

Comment: Just rechecked, with using ```cv2.resize``` function it reads binary and applies like just small part of whole camera, similar to first picture I attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get to work numpy 2d array with cv2.resize()

but finally I could get (y, x) 720,1280 array to be "scaled" to 480x640

```
for y in range(undist_grid.shape[0]):
    for x in range(undist_grid.shape[1]):
        if y % 3 != 0 and x % 2 != 0:
            yy = int((2*y) / 3)
            xx = int(x / 2)
            resized_grid[yy, xx, :] = (2 * undist_grid[y, x]) / 3
```